# Pass function as argument to another function

Tags: lambda, rust

I want to pass a function as argument to another function:

```
fn call(f: | i32, i32 | -> i32, x: i32) -> i32 {
  f(x, x)
}

fn main() {
  let res = call(| x, y | { x + y }, 4);
  println!("{}", res);
}
```

I get this error:

```
main.rs:1:12: 1:13 error: expected type, found `|`
main.rs:1 fn call(f: | i32, i32 | -> i32, x: i32) -> i32 {
```

What is the correct way to annotate function argument that is another function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function signature is probably the simplest one that works:

```
fn call<F: FnOnce(i32, i32) -> i32>(f: F, x: i32) -> i32 {
    ...
```

There is also a [section in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#taking-closures-as-arguments) that describes this.